# Vertically align bootstrap list items

Tags: html, css

I have the following - I'm stuck trying to work out how to get the yellow list item blocks to vertically align - you can see the `black dog` item is not vertically aligning because its image is not as tall as for the other two blocks, but I can't see how vertically align it so it starts at the top like the other two blocks.

```css
.gallery {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.grid {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.gallery.grid li {
  margin: 2px 5px;
}


.gallery.grid li {
  margin: 2px 5px;
  display:block;
}

.gallery.grid li:hover {
    background:#999;
}

.gallery.grid li {
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 6px;
  position: relative;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  width:200px;
  background:#000;
  color:#fff;
}

.gallery a {
    display: block;
    color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<ul class='gallery grid'>

    <li>
        <h5>The Black Dog</h5>
        <div style='text-align:center; height:400px;'>
            <img class='img-fluid rounded img-thumbnail' src='https://i.scdn.co/image/01ffab20313cca9b5d95b70a97d02e85a79a03c7' width='200' height='200'>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <h5>Coldplay</h5>
        <div style='text-align:center; height:400px;'>
            <img class='img-fluid rounded img-thumbnail' src='https://i.scdn.co/image/6397b6a29c8d9081412e09feb53600f8c9a18313' width='200' height='200'>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <h5>The Corries</h5>
        <div style='text-align:center; height:400px;'>
                <img class='img-fluid rounded img-thumbnail' src='https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e02a5a4803b3c9e3bd486505bc0' width='200' height='200'>
        </div>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Is it possible top vertically align the first block, even if the image inside it is not the same size as the other 2 blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `vertical-align: top` to `.gallery.grid li`. Like this:

```
.gallery.grid li {
    ...
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

This is because this rule should be set on elements that you want to align, but not on the parent element.

See edits in css:

```css
.gallery {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /*vertical-align: top;*/ /*remove this it*/
}

.grid {
  /*vertical-align: top;*/ /*remove this it*/
}

.gallery.grid li {
  margin: 2px 5px;
}


.gallery.grid li {
  margin: 2px 5px;
  display:block;
}

.gallery.grid li:hover {
    background:#999;
}

.gallery.grid li {
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 6px;
  position: relative;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  width:200px;
  background:#000;
  color:#fff;
  vertical-align: top; /*add this it*/
}

.gallery a {
    display: block;
    color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<ul class='gallery grid'>

    <li>
        <h5>The Black Dog</h5>
        <div style='text-align:center; height:400px;'>
            <img class='img-fluid rounded img-thumbnail' src='https://i.scdn.co/image/01ffab20313cca9b5d95b70a97d02e85a79a03c7' width='200' height='200'>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <h5>Coldplay</h5>
        <div style='text-align:center; height:400px;'>
            <img class='img-fluid rounded img-thumbnail' src='https://i.scdn.co/image/6397b6a29c8d9081412e09feb53600f8c9a18313' width='200' height='200'>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <h5>The Corries</h5>
        <div style='text-align:center; height:400px;'>
                <img class='img-fluid rounded img-thumbnail' src='https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e02a5a4803b3c9e3bd486505bc0' width='200' height='200'>
        </div>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: @4532066, always glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Add an ID to your image

```
<img class='img-fluid rounded img-thumbnail' id="myID" src='https://i.scdn.co/image/01ffab20313cca9b5d95b70a97d02e85a79a03c7' width='200' height='200'>
```

CSS:

```
#myID{
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```